# SQL Join Query in SQL Fiddle?

Tags: sql

I am working on a SQL project from one of my courses, using SQL Fiddle. Somehow I cannot extract some information, I've tried all sorts of different queries but I cannot get the correct results.

I have the following three tables:

```
A(PK:Course_Code, Course_Name)
B(PK and FK:Course_Code, PK and FK: Book_ID,)
C(PK:Book_ID, Title)
```

I want to extract the Book_ID and Title for which Course_Name = 'Data Management'.

Does anybody know the solution?
I would really appreciate your help :) 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
select C.Book_ID, C.Title
from A
join B on A.Cource_Code = B.CourseCode
join C on C.Book_ID = B.Book_ID
where A.CourseName = 'Data Management';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT C.BOOK_ID, C.TITLE
  FROM A, B, C
 WHERE A.COURSE_NAME = 'Data Management'
   AND A.COURSE_CODE = B.COURSE_CODE
   AND B.BOOK_ID = C.BOOK_ID
```